# Is a set $w \cdot z = w + z + iwz$ an abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $w \cdot z = w + z + iwz$ for every $w,z  \in \mathbb{C}$

1) Is $(\mathbb{C},\cdot)$ an abelian group?
2) Is $(\mathbb{C} \setminus \left\{ i\right\} ,\cdot)$ an abelian group?

Regarding 1) I checked that every condition is true, except inverse element because it doesn't exist for $x=i$, so $(\mathbb{C},\cdot)$ is not an abelian group.

I don't know how to to this for 2) though.

Comment: You need to show that if $w$, $z\ne i$ then $w\cdot z\ne i$.

Comment: Incidentally, $(\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ i \}, \cdot)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^*$ with the usual multiplication, since $1 + i (w \cdot z) = (1 + iw) (1 + iz)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have already covered associativity, commutativity, and identity in 1).

Restricting the set takes care of the problem you had with inverses in 1)

All that remains is closure:

In 1) you have shown that $w,z \in \mathbb C \implies w\cdot z \in \mathbb C$

But what about $w,z \in \mathbb C\setminus\{i\}$?

Suppose $\exists w,z \in \mathbb C\setminus\{i\}:w\cdot z = i$

$iwz + w + z - i = 0$

Which can be factored: $i(w-i)(z-i) = 0$

$w\cdot z = i \iff w=i,$ or $z = i$

But neither are in $C\setminus\{i\}$

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand. Where does $wz+w+z-i=0$ come from?

Comment: $w\cdot z = i \implies iwz + z+ w = i$ or $iwz +z +w - i = 0$ sorry, dropped an $i$ there didn't I.

Comment: Okay, now I see this. Is there a trick to factor $iwz+w+z-i=0$ into $i(w-i)(z-i)=0$ or you just have to guess it?

Comment: I started with the thought that $(w+1)(z+1) = wz + w+ z + 1$ so would there be some slight tweaking, I could find some factorzation that would work.  Then we knew that $z = i$ was a the source of problems, so that led me to $(z-i)$ as a factor.

Comment: Thanks. So the conclusion is that 2) is an abelian group?

Comment: Does it meet all of the criteria in the definition?